# Most General Definition of Continuity?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Currently, I am studying Topology, and I found that the definition of Continuity in Topological Spaces encompasses Continuity in Metric Spaces too.

This got me wondering - is this the *most* general form of continuity that one can define while keeping the intuitive definition of continuity intact?

If so, why is it so? What stops us from  defining it for more general spaces? And if not, can someone give some examples?

Comment: One example for _"more general spaces"_ is Scott topology, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_continuity

Comment: @JohnForkosh - the Scott topology is an actual topology, so it is an example of topology, not more general than it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuitive meaning of continuity is if a function carries $x$ to $y$, then it should carry anything close to $x$ to something close to $y$.

One can generalize the concept of function here, but I don't think that is why you are after. The only other thing to mess with is the definition of "close".

Point-set topology pushes this concept pretty much to its limit. It allows you to define closeness just by specifying set of neighbors for each point, with the only requirement being that the intersection of two neighborhoods should itself be a neighborhood. That intersection property pretty much embodies the concept of closeness. The neighborhoods may contain things extending far away from the point, but in order to be a neighborhood, they should contain everything sufficiently near the point, so everything sufficiently near should be in both - i.e., in their intersection.

Any concept of closeness should be expressible by such sets, so there isn't really any more leeway to generalize it. Any time you find something that can reasonably be considered "continuity", you will find it is expressible in terms of topologies - even if defined otherwise.

For example, the "Scott continuity" suggested by John Forkosh is defined by the requirement that the function preserve directed suprema, not limits. But then you find that you can define the Scott topology, and then Scott-continuity is just continuity under the Scott topology.

Answer (score 1):

Topological spaces are those at which the least required properties (i.e. structure) exist in order to define continuity. In fact, continous maps are exactly the structure preserving maps for topological spaces in the context of category theory. That is, the category $\mathscr{Top}$ whose objects are topological spaces and its morphisms are exactly the continous maps you are thinking of.